# How to grant ssh access to Azure App Service for a reader role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In general, what is the best role to grant an external user working to deploy and maintain an application for a limited period of time? Without allowing the creation or scaling up of resources.

Comment: Running on Linux?  Containers?

Comment: It all depends on what you would do, write or just read, deploy or just access?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Linux, Not containers

Comment: @CharlesXu deploy and write files

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly but offering alternatives to ssh and require no Azure account or role to set.

1. Set continuous deployment using GitHub, Bitbucket or Azure Repos and grant the user access to the repo, not App Service.  Each time the user will commit a change, App Service will pull it.  Remove the repo access when done.
2. Give the FTP app credentials to the user.  Reset the credentials when done.